# filter columns where index value is 0

Tags: python, pandas

In a given dataframe:
[image]

I would like to filter those columns where values are 0 for index `std`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - first select index `std`, compare and select all rows by `:` with filtered mask:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.loc['std'].eq(0)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can filter the `std` column for values that are equal to zero.

This could work: `df = num_df.loc[num_df['std'] == 0]`